# OpenFileDialog (Console)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, visual-c++, консоль

Как вызвать -> OpenFileDialog из CMD Проекта ?
Видел для Windows Forms (Получилось) а вот для консоли увы не смог... нашел материал связанный с [win32](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/microsoft.win32.openfiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx) но не вышло :(

Comment: попробуйте это сделать, используя Windows API https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646960(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вызвать диалог открытия файла, конечно, можно в любом приложении

Самый простой способ - [с помощью GetOpenFileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646829(v=vs.85).aspx#open_file)

```
OPENFILENAME ofn;       // common dialog box structure
char szFile[260];       // buffer for file name
HWND hwnd;              // owner window
HANDLE hf;              // file handle
// Initialize OPENFILENAME
ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(ofn));
ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
ofn.hwndOwner = hwnd;
ofn.lpstrFile = szFile;
// Set lpstrFile[0] to '\0' so that GetOpenFileName does not 
// use the contents of szFile to initialize itself.
ofn.lpstrFile[0] = '\0';
ofn.nMaxFile = sizeof(szFile);
ofn.lpstrFilter = "All\0*.*\0Text\0*.TXT\0";
ofn.nFilterIndex = 1;
ofn.lpstrFileTitle = NULL;
ofn.nMaxFileTitle = 0;
ofn.lpstrInitialDir = NULL;
ofn.Flags = OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST;
// Display the Open dialog box. 
if (GetOpenFileName(&ofn)==TRUE) 
    hf = CreateFile(ofn.lpstrFile, 
                    GENERIC_READ,
                    0,
                    (LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES) NULL,
                    OPEN_EXISTING,
                    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                    (HANDLE) NULL);
```

Не забудьте подключить windows.h, если еще этого не сделали.

COM-интерфейс [IFileDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776913(v=vs.85).aspx) предоставляет больше возможностей, но сложнее в использовании.

Answer (score 2):

К сожалению вы его не сможете открыть, так как он является элементом winforms и только через приложение winform вы его сможете создать, а через console вы только путь можете прописать для открытия файла.

Comment: хм, просто видел на c# делали вроде как)) ладно, спасибо :)